# HTML / CSS Contol image size dynamically?

Tags: html, css, image

Is there a way to control image size on the website ? e.g. if the image exceeds 640x360 then display it with

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="640" height="360" />
```

but if the image is less than that e.g. 256x256 then display it using its native height and width.

```
<img src="image.jpg" width="native" height="native" />
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: are you ok with javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't

```
img {max-width:640px;}
```

be the simplest answer