# Changing the size of a lot of different images with out affecting aspect ratio

Tags: css, image, gallery, aspect-ratio

Basically all I want is a whole bunch of images just one under each other. All these images are very different sizes and aspect ratios. I want all the images to be a maximum width and a maximum height without changing the aspect ratios of each image. How would i do this using html 5 and css3?

Comment: You need to give more information and demonstrate what you have tried to far. What does 'maximum' mean...the maximum size of the image or some other set number?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179957/html-css-contol-image-size-dynamically/19180049#19180049)

Comment: Try posting examples of your code so we exactly see what you (don't) want.

Answer (score 1):

Take a parent block, for example a `div` with a class name `main_div` and then add this CSS

```
.main_div img {
    width:100%;
    height: auto;
}
```